# laravel passing array through ajax gives error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm passing an array to the backend but the form request returns this error

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Exception\BadRequestException: Input value "graduation" contains a non-scalar value. in file /home/shereen/Documents/Work/S&M/jobs/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/InputBag.php on line 37

when I dd the request:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#1269   #parameters:
> array:30 [
> "university" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "education_id" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "graduation" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "degree" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "level_id" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "course_name" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "addition_information" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "company_name" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "experience_id" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "job_position" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "location" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "date_from" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "date_to" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]
> "addition_information_1" => array:1 [
> 0 => null
> ]

I don't really know what is going on, can someone help?

Comment: Please post the code. The issue is that `graduation` contains an array `[ 0 => null ]`, so you probably want to fix that in your form request.

Comment: It should be an array, I'm passing it as that

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are trying to retrieve the input through `$request->request->get('graduates')` when the **correct** way is with `$request->input('graduates')` as [documented](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-input) at 'Retrieving An Input Value'.

I am able to reproduce your error with this form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/users">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="graduates[]">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

After submitting the form with no value for graduates and trying to access the input through `$request->request->get('graduates')` the `Input value "graduates" contains a non-scalar value.` error is thrown.

This is the output of `dd($request->request);` which looks similar to yours.

```
^ Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#43 ▼
  #parameters: array:2 [▼
    "graduates" => array:1 [▼
      0 => null
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the question is about AJAX so this answer might not apply at all. Please let me know if that is so and I will delete it.

Comment: Appreciate your input, but it's AJAX